# Why pixel images enlarged with 2-4 pixel size when i downloaded on internet?

Tags: images, pixel

I'm making a game and when i downloaded image for example from anywhere it is enlarge with 1-4 size difference.And i pretty sure that images drawn with 1 pixel size.But why images enlarge?

Comment: Because of apple? See when they upped the resolutions of iphones they were suddenly very dense compared to most webpages of the time. So their options were either to say their phone is shit, or they could solve the problem by pixel doubling.

Comment: Are you talking about actually downloading an image or are you measuring it in a browser? Because that would be a different question. Also what images are you talking about, your own images, that you draw yourself? Or are you downloading stock images?

Comment: İ just download a pixel game png on internet and it enlarged 2x2 pixel size.But when i downloaded another kind of png files from another sites(not for game) it enlarged 4x4.

Answer (score 0):

The times where all displays were 72 or 96 pixels per inch are long over, not only on Apple products. To deal with higher resolution displays requires more pixels, at least 2x. Otherwise the images will get scaled up, which usually means blurry and blocky results.